# How to avoid to get a different value of accuracy each time I train my network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm studying neural networks and I have seen that each time I run my code, the obtained accuracy after the training changes. I think that it depends by the initialization of the weights, I don't know if other stuff affect it. Additionally, I would like to compare two networks, so in order to do a right comparison I would like to do something in order to get the same performance each time I run a model. Has anyone a suggestion? I'm using pytorch, and I tried to add the following code in the train.py file, before the definition of the network

```
seed = 3
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

Furthermore, in the UNET network (it is composed of convolutional layers, max-pooling layers and batch normalization layers), I added the following row before each convolutional layer:

```
torch.manual_seed(3)
```

However, each time I train the model, the obtained performance changes.

Comment: GPU computations are also not always deterministic (they have some random noise)

Comment: So there is no way to get always the same performances, is it?

Comment: Well your approach should work as far as I remember. If your difference comes from the computations, then perhaps your model is unstable by itself. Is the difference that large? If the accuracy changes by 0.001, it shouldn't be much of an issue

Comment: I tried to run only 3 epochs in a small portion of the dataset, and I get once 0,1850 and the second time 0,1940. I don't know if I increase the number of epochs and I consider the whole dataset, If the difference reduces.

Comment: I think your issue is with your approach. From what I can understand you are not actually altering the model between training and thus want the same accuracy/output/model so you can compare against other models or methods? // The extremely common approach is to train the modal once, save the weights, then reload the model weights during validation/prediction/testing. This will always produce the same performance because you are not altering network weights with unneeded back passes. You only forward pass through the reloaded from disk network.

Comment: The point is that I would like to compare two models, but if I train one time the two networks I get for example, for model1  and model2 respectively 0,9290 and 0,9370. Then if I train exactly the same models, I get for model1 and model2 respectively 0,9310 and 0,9360. Thus, I don't know which values I should consider in order to make a right comparison, so I thought that maybe I should reduce the randomness.

Comment: Ref the seed_everything implmentation of pytorch-lightning https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pytorch_lightning/utilities/seed.html#seed_everything